# Selecting columns with condition on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe looking like this.

```
    col1    col2
0   something1  something1
1   something2  something3
2   something1  something1
3   something2  something3
4   something1  something2
```

I'm trying to filter all rows that have `something1` either on `col1` or `col2`. If I just need the condition logic on a column, I can do it with `df[df.col1 == 'something1']` but would there be a way to do it with multiple columns?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print ((df == 'something1').all(1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool

print (df[(df == 'something1').all(1)])
         col1        col2
0  something1  something1
2  something1  something1
```

EDIT:

If need select only some columns you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for selecting desired `columns` and then use `subset` - `df[cols]`:

```
print (df)
         col1        col2 col3
0  something1  something1    a
1  something2  something3    s
2  something1  something1    r
3  something2  something3    a
4  something1  something2    a

cols = df.columns[df.columns.isin(['col1','col2'])]
print (cols)
Index(['col1', 'col2'], dtype='object')

print (df[(df[cols] == 'something1').all(1)])
         col1        col2 col3
0  something1  something1    a
2  something1  something1    r
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael! 
Additional question: If I want to filter for specific columns (say, only in col1 and col2 but I have other columns), do you know how to do it? I guess I need to replace .all(1) with something else?

Comment: hmmm, these columns has common part of column name? - `col` for `col1` and `col2` ?

Comment: Oh for example, if I have col1, col2 and col3 but I want to look through only col1 and col2 but not col3.

Answer (score 15):

Why not:

```
df[(df.col1 == 'something1') | (df.col2 == 'something1')]
```

outputs:

```
    col1    col2
0   something1  something1
2   something1  something1
4   something1  something2
```

Comment: Why not...? :):)

Answer (score 2):

To apply one condition to the whole dataframe

```
df[(df == 'something1').any(axis=1)]
```