# How to access another column's value from a given id number in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following format of DataFrame:

```
# import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# Creating a dictionary
d = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
     'label': ['bal', 'sal', 'tal'], 
     } 
  
# Creating a Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d) 
  
# show the dataframe
print(df)
```

> Output:

```
  id label
0  a   bal
1  b   sal
2  c   tal
```

I have `id = 'b'`. Now I want to access the corresponding `label` value like `label = 'sal'`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting columns with condition on Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37663931/selecting-columns-with-condition-on-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: `df.loc[df.id=='b', 'label']`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [21]: df.set_index('id').loc['b', 'label']
Out[21]: 'sal'
```

Or, use `df.query`:

```
In [28]: df.query('id == "b"')['label']
Out[28]: 
1    sal
Name: label, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

`df.loc[df.id == 'b', 'label']`